# Página que añade contenido en blanco a la derecha en móviles

Tags: html, css, web

estoy haciendo una página web, y cuando trabaja con resoluciones de dispositivos móviles, añade un margen blanco extraño, le he dado a inspeccionar elemento, y no corresponde a nada, está fuera del body o html, y estos no tienen margenes, ni padding.

¿Por qué sucede esto?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://retewe.es/mundisabor         (Meteros con móvil para ver el problema)

Answer (score 0):

Esta sección de la etiqueta causa el dicho espacio. si la borras verás que el overflow-x no estará.

[image: Imagen de dicho problema.]

Comment: ¡Gracias amigo! Lo había solucionado con un overflow-x tanto al body como al html, pero me había quedado la intriga de qué es lo que realmente pasaba. ¿Cómo has logrado saberlo, y por qué motivo pasaba?

Comment: lo encontré de una manera muy bruta y fácil, comencé a eliminar etiquetas por etiqueta hasta que el overflow-x no se mostrara.